# I am not able to be susceptible

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is used half the time,
>   My infix is self-referencing;
>   My suffix is a group of adults,
>   My whole is an agreement.

What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My prefix is used half the time,

> am - ante meridiem or before midday

My infix is self-referencing;

> me - refers to myself

My suffix is a group of adults,

> men - adult male humans

My whole is an agreement.

> amen - so be it, truly, verily in agreement

Title: I am not able to be susceptible

> Unamenable as insusceptible, from amenable as susceptible